# MKAnnotation - Map Pin callout pops up behind other map pins

Tags: iphone

My map pins can be quite densely populated so that when a pin is selected the callout pops up but is mostly obscured by all the other map pins - I can bring the Map Pin to the front it there were a delegate for selected map pin ( not tapped callout, selected pin ).

Any suggestions for a work around ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom annotation views you can add an observer for the selected property which would act like a delegate for when the pin is selected.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKAnnotation *annview = ...code to either dequeue or create new object...
    [annview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"selectedmapannotation"];               
    return annview;
}
```

then you can monitor the selected state with

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context;
```

The answer linked by Mugunth Kumar will also give you the desired results it's just that you made mention of delegate like functionality in your question.

EDIT:

Here is an example of the contents of the observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: method

```
NSString *action = (NSString*)context;

if([action isEqualToString:@"selectedmapannotation"]){
    BOOL annotationAppeared = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];
    MKAnnotationView *ann = (MKAnnotationView *)object;

    if (annotationAppeared) {
        // do something with the annotation when it is selected
    }
    else {
        // do something with the annotation when it is de-selected
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this?  what would the observeValueForKeyPath implementation actually look like?  can you give an example?

Comment: edited the answer to add an example implementation, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

UICallout view is the subview of the MKAnnotationView. So, I think if you will bring Map ping to the front, UICAlloutView will be there too.

Comment: how do you bring the UICalloutView to the front programmatically?