# MKMapView: Pins over the pop up

Tags: cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

This question was asked earlier by someone else but never answered: [MKAnnotation - Map Pin callout pops up behind other map pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458052/mkannotation-map-pin-callout-pops-up-behind-other-map-pins).

I ran into this problem yesturday and I have no clue what caused this problem and was hoping someone else has had this problem but figured it out.

[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/78/screenshot20100119at938.jpg](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/78/screenshot20100119at938.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might want to take a look at the responses here:

[Z-ordering of MKAnnotationViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681565/z-ordering-of-mkannotationviews/1681993)

Comment: I have the same problem but not on the callout. My problem seems to appear on the pin itself because they are very close.
It can be call clipping problem. But how to resolve it ?